# How to make a navbar sticky?

Tags: html, css, navbar, sticky

I made a working navbar but I can't make it sticky. I tried `position: fixed` and `top: 0` but they couldn't! help. They made it worse. Can someone help how to make it sticky?

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("background.png");
  background-position: center top;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-size: auto;
}

#first {
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

a:hover,
a:visited,
a:link,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 5vh;
  font-family: "Minecraft Regular", sans-serif;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 35%;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#register {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6c7575, #5e8b94);
  padding: 1.5vh;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-right: 5vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <h4 id="logo-text">de_ducks2</h4>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#first">Kezdőlap</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ninth">Kapcsolat</a></li>
    <li><a href="i.html" id="register">Regisztráció</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="randomfaszaanimation">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The other parts are for the mobile view. If they can have an effect on the sticky working, I will send them too. The whole website is available here: https://zsombitech.github.io/DeDucks2-Website/.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try `position: sticky; top: 0;` This is a built-in css rule which fluctuates the position of the element between fixed and static depending on the scroll position. Here is an example:

```css
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  outline: 3px solid #000;
}

.content {
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  background: #afa;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
  <div class="navbar">This is the navbar</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum..... Scroll down... Watch the navbar stay in one place... <br><br><br><br><br>Here is some more content.</div>
  
</div>
```

In your case this is not working because the body has the css rule `overflow-x: hidden`. So, you can inject this into the console: `document.body.style.overflowX = "initial";`, and after that `position: sticky; top: 0px;` should work for the `nav` element. Make sure that the `nav` element is directly in the body, otherwise it will hide once you scroll past `section one`.

Comment: Then the problem would be to do with some other styles . Just give me a minute to read through your css

Comment: Thanks, the full CSS code is available through the website (if needed)

Comment: Hmm position fixed seems to work but sticky does not

Comment: Yeah, I just entered this in the console: `document.querySelector(".logo").parentElement.setAttribute("style","position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); width: 100%;");`

Comment: But .logo is a logo on the corner and when I tried(I added the properties to the logo element) it didn't work. Do you have other tips?

Comment: .logo is the logo, but I am injecting the styles into its parentElement.

Comment: Oh, it works in firefox but not in chromium

Comment: If I inject this code "position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); width: 100%;" into .nav, it can work in firefox?

Comment: The problem is caused by the stylesheet which has `href="assets/styles/style.css"`. And yes, it did for me in FireFox.

Comment: And also, move the nav so that it is a direct child of `body` otherwise position sticky will not work even if we resolve the issue in `assets/styles/style.css`

Comment: Ok, Ive got it. Place the nav directly inside the body, then inject this into the console: `document.body.style.overflowX = "initial";`

Comment: After that, `position: sticky; top: 0px;` should work

Comment: So I moved navbar into body (directly), I ran the site, in the developer tools I added this document.body.style.overflowX = "initial"; to the console, I added this document.body.style.overflowX = "initial"; to .nav, but I didn't work

Comment: You helped a lot

Comment: No problem :) .

Comment: I've changed my answer so that it covers our discussion.